# Permission denied when run docker

Tags: docker, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied

I recently moved docker files from /var/lib/docker to /home/username/.docker. After that, when running docker, an error began to occur:
`WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/username/.docker/config.json: open /home/username/.docker/config.json: permission denied`

The problem is solved as follows:

```
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R
```

But when restart the docker service or rebooting system, the rights to the .docker folder automatically changes to the root user and the error is repeated.